# Blobstore: is service down?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm experiencing a strange problem with file uploads to Blobstore (runtime: Java, appid: teamwork-client-services). POSTing a request with file data from client's browser to Blobstore service URL (retrieved via call to createUploadUrl()) causes a status 500 response with no explanation. Request gets never redirected to my server-side upload handler.

Just checked two other applications (one of them uses Python runtime). Got the same behavior. GAE System Status console shows 100% availability, but I'm not sure if Blobstore status is monitored there.

Could anyone help me figure out what's going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is localized to a very specific moment in time, and is about the status of a Google service, not programming.

Comment: @Wooble Quite possibly. Previously I used to post this kind of questions to Google Groups. But since GAE team announced that they're migrating their support here (["We’re pleased to announce that we are migrating to Stack Overflow as the official channel for answering development questions about Google App Engine."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w)), I decided to leave a question on Stack Overflow. However, if you can suggest me more specific topic/tag for this question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just letting you guys know - seems like the Google AppEngine team agnoledged the problem and **solved** it just now:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/jWjCxoPOP8Y

Comment: Thank you for the update and useful link to their downtime notification group! For some reason I never noticed that one.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same thing, started happening today - we didn't change anything so we assume it is an internal breakage in one of the blobstore service mechanims